# how to filter array to only pick last changed value of same id of object in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, onchange

This is the function i run on OnChange in AvField

```
let selectedFieldArray = []

const templateValue = (e) => {
    const fieldObject = {
      "id": e.target.name,
      "value": e.target.value,
    }
    selectedFieldArray.push(fieldObject)
    const uniqueID = selectedFieldArray.filter((obj, id, array) => {
      return id === array.findIndex((t) => (
        t.id === obj.id
      )) 
    })
  }
```

but in uniqueID it only picks first object of array not the last updated object in array.

Comment: Please provide sample data, result you are trying to achieve and how your output is different from desired result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `arr.findIndex` you can use `arr.findLastIndex`

```js
let selectedFieldArray = [];
const templateValue = (e) => {
  const fieldObject = {
    "id": e.target.name,
    "value": e.target.value,
  }
  selectedFieldArray.push(fieldObject) const uniqueID = selectedFieldArray.filter((obj, id, array) => {
    return id === array.findLastIndex((t) => (t.id === obj.id))
  })
}
```